# WPF, Stored Animations to play when necessary?

Tags: wpf, animation

It's possible to store Animations and then assign to object when necessary ?

Example: In-Out Animation on CanvasControl "myCanvas1".

bool Is_myCanvas1Expanded;

if (Is_myCanvas1Expanded) { //retreive; }
   else { //expand; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using story board for animation then it has StoryBoard.Begin and  StoryBoard.Pause , StoryBoard.Resume and StoryBoard.Stop method which will serve your purpose.

What you can do is assign storyboard to control and then apply above operation as per your requirement.

For your Reference

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard_methods(v=vs.110).aspx